# Using password_hash and password_verify

Tags: php

In my Login PHP file I have these

```
$passwordInput = password_hash($passInput, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$passwordVerify = password_verify($userInput, $passwordInput);
```

And in my Register PHP file I have this.

```
$passwordSign = password_hash($passSign, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Now, essentially I make it so it hashes the password and inserts itself into the database on signup. WHICH IT DOES.

However, it cannot verify it. Both results give 2 different hashes and I don't know what I'm possibly doing wrong. I also tried just making it hash the input again and checking the password_hash in the database but that didn't work..

What is the proper way of using these?

( Also, $passSign and $userInput are the input fields and it does get the username/password )

Comment: Are you sure the variable names are correct? Specially `$passInput` and `$userInput` ?

Comment: Instead of deleting the original question's body after figured out the solution, please add your solution as answer to help others.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On signup you get the password from the user input and generate its has using [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

```
$hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

You can provide it a custom salt to use, in a third parameter, but the documentation [recommends](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-notes) to not do this:

> **Caution** It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one.

You save this hash in the database. Make sure you put it in a `CHAR`/`VARCHAR` **field of 60 characters or longer**.

When the user wants to log in you check the password they input against the hash previously saved using [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php):

```
$auth = password_verify($_POST['password'], $hash);
```

Of course, you get the correct value of `$hash` from the database, searching by the provided username.

If `$auth` is `TRUE` then the provided password matches its hash computed on the registration and the user is authenticated.

Comment: How would you perform a db lookup of a user account, assuming that you have the fields 'user_name' and 'user_pass' in the database.Assume hundreds of users, with unique 'user_name' (unique checked during user registration). You can't lookup by condition of user_name and user_pass. You can't use password_verify because you don't know the right record to select (assume that there might be duplicate passwords but each has a different user_name). So do you have to query for user_name, then loop through 1+ results to check for password_verify? Thanks.

Comment: You said in the second sentence: *"Assume hundreds of users, with unique 'user_name'"*. When you search by 'user_name' you either find one record in the database or you don't find any. Create an `UNIQUE INDEX` on the 'user_name' column in the database to help it run fast and to enforce the uniqueness.

Comment: The docs recommend storing the hash in a 255-length varchar field, because the algorithm can change in future PHP versions without notice.